# ¿Como puedo enviar un array o concatenar correctamente varios campos y enviarlos a mi strore procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server

** ********************Inicio de la Solución******************** **

```
    create procedure spGenBK_Consultar_Array  
    @guia  varchar(8000),
    @Fecha char(4),    
    @Prod char(1) ,    
    @Cliente char(8),
    @CodReferenciaFac varchar(4) ='',
    @CodReferenciaweb varchar(4) = ''    

    as  
    BEGIN
    declare @vSql  varchar(8000)  

    set  @vSql = 'select  
    gdn.pro_cod as Producto,    
    gn.guia_bill_pag_ref as Cliente,    
    gdn.guia_ano as OrdenAnio,    

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = ''00288710'' and gdn.pro_cod = ''NAC''     
    then isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'''')    
    else gdn.guia_nro    
    END as OrdenNro,     

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = ''00288710'' and gdn.pro_cod = ''NAC''     
    then ''''    
    ELSE isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'''')    
    END as OrdenNroRef,    

    gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref as Guia,     
    convert(varchar, gdn.guia_det_fch_emi, 103) as FechaEmi,    
    replace(substring(gdn.GUIA_DET_CON_CIA,0,100),'''','''') as Consignatario,     
    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = ''00288710'' and gdn.pro_cod = ''NAC''     
    then rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref )    
    ELSE rtrim(gdn.guia_det_con_cuent_refer)    
    end as Cuenta,      

    guia_servicio as serviciocod,     
    ref_cod as ReferenciaCod,    
    ref_fac_cod as CenCostoCod,     
    gdd_new_imei as ImeiEntrega,    
    gdd_dev_imei as ImeiRecojo,    
    gdd_dev_telf as Telefono,     
    rtrim(isnull(guia_det_nro_master,'''')) as Master,     
    gdn.guia_det_id as GuiaDetId        


    from guia_detalle_nacional as gdn WITH(NOLOCK)       ' 

    set @vSql =@vSql+ ' join guia_nacional as gn WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on  gn.empr_cod = gdn.empr_cod    
    and gn.suc_cod = gdn.suc_cod    
    and gn.uni_neg_cod = gdn.uni_neg_cod    
    and gn.pro_cod = gdn.pro_cod    
    and gn.guia_ano = gdn.guia_ano    
    and gn.guia_nro = gdn.guia_nro    

    left join gdn_detalle as det WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on det.guia_det_id = gdn.guia_det_id    

    where  
    gdn.empr_cod = ''00040007''    
    and gdn.uni_neg_cod = ''SLG''     
    and YEAR( gdn.guia_det_fch_emi) = '''+@Fecha+'''
    and gdn.pro_cod = case  '''+@Prod+'''
    when ''1'' then ''NAC''                                      
    when ''2'' then ''MET''                                      
    when ''3'' then gdn.pro_cod                                      
    end     '

    set @vSql =@vSql+ ' and gn.guia_shi_cod = '''+ @Cliente +''' '

    set @vSql =@vSql+ ' and rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref) in (' + rtrim(ltrim(@guia ))+ ')
    and isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'''')=case when '''+@CodReferenciaFac +''' ='''' then isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'''') else '''+@CodReferenciaFac+''' end  
    and isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'''')=case when '''+ @CodReferenciaweb +''' ='''' then isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'''') else '''+@CodReferenciaweb+''' end   '

    exec (@vSql)

    end
```

** ********************Fin de la Solución******************** **

tengo un caso. Yo quisiera enviar un array de datos que obtengo desde Un bucle(aquí es donde quisiera saber cómo concatenar correctamente para mandarlo al SP, o quizas alojarlo en un array list y mandarlo al SP.

Ejemplo del SP:

```
Sp_consultar_detalle
@guia varchar(5000, según sea el caso la cantidad que vaya a 
concatenar o recibir),
@año date
As
Select *
From detalle_guias with(nolock)
Where nro_guia IN(@guia)
And fecha_guia = year(@ño)
```

Llamando al Sp:
Exec Sp_cobsultar_detalle (@guia=‘guia1’,’guia2’,etc, @año=2018, etc)--> Es una idea

Que funcione algo así:

```
select  * from GUIA_DETALLE_NACIONAL with (nolock)
where rtrim(Guia_det_nro_ref) in ('1010968487-1','1010968485-2')
```

En mi aplicación de C# tengo un For que recorre un Excel y obtienes los números de guía , luego llama al SP y es aquí donde no se como concatenar esos números de guía para mandarlo como un parámetro.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

**TODO ESTO ES MI Store Procedure REAL, me puedes dar una mano para como modificar con los datos que me recomiendas.**

```
    create procedure spGenBK_Consultar_Masivo  
    @guia varchar(max),
    @Fecha char(6),    
    @Prod char(1) ,    
    @Cliente char(8),
    @CodReferenciaFac varchar(4) ='',
    @CodReferenciaweb varchar(4) = ''    

    as    
    select  
    gdn.pro_cod as Producto,    
    gn.guia_bill_pag_ref as Cliente,    
    gdn.guia_ano as OrdenAnio,    

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = '00288710' and gdn.pro_cod = 'NAC'     
    then isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'')    
    else gdn.guia_nro    
    END as OrdenNro,     

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = '00288710' and gdn.pro_cod = 'NAC'     
    then ''    
    ELSE isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'')    
    END as OrdenNroRef,    

    gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref as Guia,     
    convert(varchar, gdn.guia_det_fch_emi, 103) as FechaEmi,    
    replace(substring(gdn.GUIA_DET_CON_CIA,0,100),'''','') as Consignatario,     
    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = '00288710' and gdn.pro_cod = 'NAC'     
    then rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref )    
    ELSE rtrim(gdn.guia_det_con_cuent_refer)    
    end as Cuenta,      

    guia_servicio as serviciocod,     
    ref_cod as ReferenciaCod,    
    ref_fac_cod as CenCostoCod,     
    gdd_new_imei as ImeiEntrega,    
    gdd_dev_imei as ImeiRecojo,    
    gdd_dev_telf as Telefono,     
    rtrim(isnull(guia_det_nro_master,'')) as Master,     
    gdn.guia_det_id as GuiaDetId        


    from guia_detalle_nacional as gdn WITH(NOLOCK)    

    join guia_nacional as gn WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on  gn.empr_cod = gdn.empr_cod    
    and gn.suc_cod = gdn.suc_cod    
    and gn.uni_neg_cod = gdn.uni_neg_cod    
    and gn.pro_cod = gdn.pro_cod    
    and gn.guia_ano = gdn.guia_ano    
    and gn.guia_nro = gdn.guia_nro    

    left join gdn_detalle as det WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on det.guia_det_id = gdn.guia_det_id    

    where  
    gdn.empr_cod = '00040007'    
    and gdn.uni_neg_cod = 'SLG'     
    and rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref) in (@guia)
    and YEAR( gdn.guia_det_fch_emi) = @Fecha
    and gdn.pro_cod = case  @Prod                                     
    when '1' then 'NAC'                                      
    when '2' then 'MET'                                      
    when '3' then gdn.pro_cod                                      
    end     

    and gn.guia_shi_cod =@Cliente
    and isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'')=case when @CodReferenciaFac='' then isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'') else @CodReferenciaFac end
    and isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'')=case when @CodReferenciaweb='' then isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'') else @CodReferenciaweb end
```

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar a un procedure una lista de valores se utiliza el `Table-Valued Parameters`

[Parámetros con valores de tabla](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Entonces no necesitas concatener nada, puedes pasar lo valores en una lista

```
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertCategories", connection);  
insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpNewCategories", dataReader);  
tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

El procesure se invoca usando el `SqlCommand` sin ningun EXEC ya que se define el

```
CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Dentro del procedure pudes usar el `INNER JOIN` para relacionar los valores del parametro con la tabla, no necesitas del `IN`

Comment: **@Leandro Tuttuni** , tendras algun ejemplo real para poder hacer el intento, lamentablemente no logro comprender tu respuesta.

Comment: pero el codigo que puse es un ejemplo real, leiste el link que propuse ? basicamente se basa en definir parametros definiendo una estructura de tabla para pasar la lista

Comment: Acabo de poner mi store procedure que uso actualmente, me puedes dar una mano de como debería hacer eso. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: pero leiste el articulo? ademas el procedure es solo una parte, como lo invocas desde c# es la otra, tienes que usar parametros, si usas el EXEC no aplica para poder enviar un Table-Valued Parameters

Comment: woooouuu, se pone más complicado. Seguiré intentando.  Muchas Gracias.

Comment: no deberia ser complicado, el camino correcto es usar parametros, canocatener en un string los valores es una pesima practica

Comment: Logre solucionarlo.  Detallo el código que use. Muchas gracias.